# Breaking script output from one huge CSV to smaller CSVs

Tags: powershell, csv, output

Currently have a script that will run through all the user files on a server and output them based upon last access time.  Client wants a report of the files that haven't been touched in the last year.

Problem is, the report is just too large. I'm estimating over a two million line CSV based off my test sample set.  So instead of one **HUGE** file, Id like to convert this script to output many smaller reports, broken down by user.

Scan a root users directory, spit out a CSV with that users name, then iterate to the next user, and repeat.

```
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).addYears(-1)
$arr = @()
$exclusions = @(".lnk",".url",".ini",".odc",".ctx",".upd",".ica")

gci "D:\USER_FILES\company\USERS\Lname, Fname" -Recurse | ? {
  $_.PSIsContainer -eq $False -and
  $_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate -and
  $exclusions -notcontains $_.Extension -and
  $_.length -gt "0" -and
  $_.Directory -notmatch ".*USERS\\.*\\Personal\\sysdata\\cookies"
} | % {
  $obj = New-Object PSObject
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty MB ("{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB))
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty created $_.creationtime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccessed $_.LastAccessTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastMofified $_.LastWriteTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension
  $arr += $obj
}

$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "C:\Output.csv"
```

**Below is the edit - output to pipeline instead of an array**

```
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).addYears(-1)
$exclusions = @(".lnk",".url",".ini",".odc",".ctx",".upd",".ica")

Get-ChildItem 'D:\USER_FILES\company\USERS' | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $name = $_.Name
  Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse |
    ? {
      $exclusions -notcontains $_.Extension -and
      $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and
      $_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate -and
      $_.length -gt "0" -and
      $_.Directory -notmatch '.*USERS\\.*\\Personal\\sysdata\\cookies'
    } |
    select DirectoryName, Name, @{n='MB';e={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB)}},
           CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Extension |
    Export-Csv "D:\User-Files-Output\$name.csv" -NoType
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of it writing the CSV as soon as it hits the conditions statement]

**Note:** Disregard the initial path, I'm testing in a diff environment at the moment, so C drive or D, the root path is still USERS.

Comment: If a report is too large then summarise it. You could for example load your CSV into Excel and run a pivot table on it then analyse counts by user, access bucket (1 month, 2 month, 1 year etc.)., file size. I've always found that this is an iterative process. Once the client sees a report they think of something else they want. Giving them a cross tab with some useful groupings (is there a useful user hierarchy i.e. by department) satisfies this very quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the user folders (assuming that your user folders are folders named `Lastname, Firstname` inside `D:\USER_FILES\company\USERS`), then recurse into them for each user. Also, don't append to an array in a loop. Just select your properties and pipe the output into `Export-Csv`. If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can use the parameters `-File` and `-Directory` to restrict the output of `Get-ChildItem` to files or folders respectively.

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\USER_FILES\company\USERS' -Directory | % {
  $name = $_.Name
  Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -File |
    ? {
      $_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate -and
      $exclusions -notcontains $_.Extension -and
      $_.length -gt "0" -and
      $_.Directory -notmatch '.*USERS\\.*\\Personal\\sysdata\\cookies'
    } |
    select DirectoryName, Name, @{n='MB';e={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB)}},
           CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Extension |
    Export-Csv "C:\$name.csv" -NoType
}
```

If you're restricted to PowerShell v2 change the above to this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\USER_FILES\company\USERS' | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $name = $_.Name
  Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse |
    ? {
      -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
      $_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate -and
      $exclusions -notcontains $_.Extension -and
      $_.length -gt "0" -and
      $_.Directory -notmatch '.*USERS\\.*\\Personal\\sysdata\\cookies'
    } |
    select DirectoryName, Name, @{n='MB';e={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB)}},
           CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Extension |
    Export-Csv "C:\$name.csv" -NoType
}
```

Comment: Receiving this error and can't see why.                                          Missing expression after ','.
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\agedFiles.ps1:12 char:74
+     select DirectoryName, Name, @{n='MB';e={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB)}, <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

Comment: @soMuch2Learn The calculated property was missing a closing curly bracket. Fixed.

Comment: Copy that.  Thank you.

Comment: Having an issue with the `-not $_.PSIsContainer` condition.  Using debugger, it just never gets passed this condition.  Using PowerGUI debugger, it iterates through, but anything that is a file, it just skips and results in empty CSV files being output.  Any ideas?  Tried `!$_.PSIsContainer` and `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false' but its not evaluating this boolean to $true when it hits a file.

Comment: In fact, doesn't matter what order i place the "filters" in. It never gets passed the first one and just spits out empty CSVs.

Comment: Ok, placed the edits using your code into the original question.  Also a screenshot showing that as soon as it hits the conditionals/filters, it generates a CSV and the debugger just sits where it's highlighted in the screenshot.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter what order i place the filters in, PSIsContainer, $exclusions, $_.length, etc.  Just highlights the first one and starts generating the CSVs.

Comment: @soMuch2Learn It's a pipeline, so it's supposed to start writing as soon as the first item comes through. Did you verify that the entirety of your conditions actually lets anything through (i.e. did you try removing conditions to see what effect that has)? I just double-checked the code and AFAICS it works as intended.

Comment: Yes, commenting out the conditions yields all the files, over the properly named CSV files.  Ill have to see why my exclusions are an issue.  Thanks Ansgar, your method is lightening fast.

Comment: The offending condition is `$_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate`.  Removing that and all the other conditions run fine.

Comment: nevermind.  it works as is.  the real offender is the second check for the `PSIsContainer`, which is not needed.  thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic of your last line:

```
 $arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "C:\Output.csv"
```

into the final `ForEach-Object` script block:

```
$obj | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ("C:\{0}.csv" -f $user)
```

You'll need to grab the user's name from each item's path, e.g.

```
$_.FullName -match 'D:\\USER_FILES\\company\\USERS\\([^\\]+)\\' | Out-Null
$user = $Matches[1]
```

So, your final `ForEach-Object` script block looks like this:

```
$_.FullName -match 'D:\\USER_FILES\\company\\USERS\\([^\\]+)\\' | Out-Null
$user = $Matches[1]    
New-Object PSObject |
    Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty MB ("{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB)) -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty created $_.creationtime -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccessed $_.LastAccessTime -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty LastMofified $_.LastWriteTime -PassThru |
    Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension -PassThru |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ('C:\{0}.csv' -f $user)
```